# PySpark equivalent of Flatmapgroups RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, flatmap

I have a data like below:

```
+----+----+
|user|item|
+----+----+
|   a|   1|
|   a|   2|
|   a|   3|
|   b|   1|
|   b|   5|
|   b|   4|
|   b|   7|
|   c|  10|
|   c|   2|
+----+----+
```

I would like to have the data after some transformation like as follows:

```
(a,(a,1))
(a,(a,2))
(a,(a,3))
(b,(b,1))
(b,(b,5))
(b,(b,4))
(b,(b,7))
(c,(c,10))
(c,(c,2))
```

They might be separate rdds. It would be ok for me.

It could be done using dataset and a combination of groupbykey and flatmapgroups in scala and java, but unfortunately there is no dataset or flatmapgroups in pyspark.

I tried some flatmap and flatmapvalues transformation on pypsark, but I couldn't manage to get the correct results.

How could I get the expected results via using pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please have look on my below code. I think you could be able to find a solution using this code snippet.

> [root@sandbox work]# hadoop dfs -put sample.txt /user/

sample.txt

```
a|1
a|2
a|3
b|1
b|5
b|4
b|7
c|10
c|2
```

> [root@sandbox work]#pyspark

```
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://sandbox/user/sample.txt")

def parse(line):
    return (line.split('|')[0], (line.split('|')[0], line.split('|')[1]))

parsed_lines = lines.map(parse)

parsed_lines.collect()

[(u'a', (u'a', u'1')), (u'a', (u'a', u'2')), (u'a', (u'a', u'3')), (u'b', (u'b', u'1')), (u'b', (u'b', u'5')), (u'b', (u'b', u'4')), (u'b', (u'b', u'7')), (u'c', (u'c', u'10')), (u'c', (u'c', u'2'))]
```